# Share Firestore collection path and model type mapping between TypeScript Firebase SDK and Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I share Firestore collection path and model type mapping between TypeScript Firebase SDK and Firebase Admin SDK?

## Example

Following code works, but it does not share collection path and model type mapping like { "courses": Course, "sections": Section }.

### types.ts

```
export interface Course {
  id: string;
}

export interface Section {
  id: string;
}
```

### collectionPath.ts

```
export const collectionPaths = {
  courses: "courses",
  sections: "sections",
};
```

### orm.ts

```
import {
  collection,
  Firestore,
  FirestoreDataConverter,
  PartialWithFieldValue,
  QueryDocumentSnapshot,
  DocumentData,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { collectionPaths } from "./collectionPaths";
import { Course, Section } from "./types";

const converter = <T>(): FirestoreDataConverter<T> => ({
  toFirestore: (data: PartialWithFieldValue<T>) => data as DocumentData,
  fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => snap.data() as T,
});

export const admin = (firestore: Firestore) => {
  const dataPoint = <T>(collectionPath: string) =>
    collection(firestore, collectionPath).withConverter(converter<T>());

  return {
    couses: dataPoint<Course>(collectionPaths.courses),
    sections: dataPoint<Section>(collectionPaths.sections),
  };
};
```

### adminOrm.ts

```
import { firestore } from "firebase-admin";
import {
  FirestoreDataConverter,
  WithFieldValue,
  QueryDocumentSnapshot,
  DocumentData,
} from "firebase-admin/firestore";
import { collectionPaths } from "./collectionPaths";
import { Course, Section } from "./types";

const converter = <T>(): FirestoreDataConverter<T> => ({
  toFirestore: (data: WithFieldValue<T>) => data as DocumentData,
  fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => snap.data() as T,
});

export const adminOrm = (firestore: firestore.Firestore) => {
  const dataPoint = <T>(collectionPath: string) =>
    firestore.collection(collectionPath).withConverter(converter<T>());

  return {
    couses: dataPoint<Course>(collectionPaths.courses),
    sections: dataPoint<Section>(collectionPaths.sections),
  };
};
```

## What I've tried

I've tried following code, but it loses `ModelType` for `CollectionReference<ModelType>`.

### collectionPaths.ts

```
import { Course, Section } from "./types";

export class CollectionPath<T> {
  path: string;

  constructor(path: string) {
    this.path = path;
  }
}

export const collectionPaths = {
  courses: new CollectionPath<Course>("courses"),
  sections: new CollectionPath<Section>("sections"),
};
```

### adminOrm.ts

```
import { firestore } from "firebase-admin";
import {
  FirestoreDataConverter,
  WithFieldValue,
  QueryDocumentSnapshot,
  DocumentData,
  CollectionReference,
} from "firebase-admin/firestore";
import { collectionPaths } from "./collectionPaths";

const converter = <T>(): FirestoreDataConverter<T> => ({
  toFirestore: (data: WithFieldValue<T>) => data as DocumentData,
  fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => snap.data() as T,
});

export const adminOrm = (firestore: firestore.Firestore) => {
  const dataPoint = <T>(collectionPath: string) =>
    firestore.collection(collectionPath).withConverter(converter<T>());

  return <{ [key in keyof typeof collectionPaths]: CollectionReference }>(
    Object.entries(collectionPaths).reduce(
      (p, [k, v]) => Object.assign(p, { [k]: dataPoint(v.path) }),
      {}
    )
  );
};
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you mean by "share collection path and model type mapping".  I dont' have a clear sense of the problem you're trying to solve and the issues you have with the implementation.  Ideally you should share what you tried that does **not** work, along with any error messages or debugging details.

Comment: Are you looking for [How to share typescript class between firebase cloud functions and angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801733/how-to-share-typescript-class-between-firebase-cloud-functions-and-angular) or [Sharing code between Firebase Functions and React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55861531/sharing-code-between-firebase-functions-and-react)?

Comment: I'm still not clear what you mean by "it loses a model type".

Comment: can you please elaborate your question in a more detailed way, also check this [share firestore collection paths across admin and web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67930431/share-firestore-collection-paths-across-admin-and-web)